# Riemann sums: What is the difference between an upper sum/upper bound and lower sum/lower bound?

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

I'm having trouble finding the difference between an upper sum and an upper bound (same with lower sum and lower bound). What's the difference between them?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! An upper sum for the interval $[a,b]$ is the sum of the upperbounds of the values of the function on the successive small intervals that make up a partition of $[a,b]$ times the length of the small interval. Similarly for the lower sum. Is that clear?

Comment: I suggest you try to deal with the simpler idea first. Can you define the term "upper bound of a set" in your own words with minimal symbols? Next you should try to define "supremum of a set" (this one is more complicated than upper bound, but you need to deal with it). If you have done these two tasks then it is easy to define an upper sum for a function.

Comment: Always try to formulate definitions in your own words with minimal symbols. Doing that helps you to know what you have really understood and what's troubling you. And then you can get the exact help you need on MSE.